# Deserialize Array using borsh js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, serialization

I'm using borsh to serialise and deserialise.

```
class something {
  val_1 = 0
  val_2 = 0
  constructor(fields: {val_1: number, val_2: number} | undefined=undefined) {
    if(fields) {
      this.val_1 = fields.val_1
      this.val_2 = fields.val_2
    }
  }
}

const somethingSchema = new Map([
  [something, {kind: 'struct', fields: [
    ['val_1', 'u128'], ['val_2', 'u128']
  ]}]
])

const decoded_data = borsh.deserialize(something, somethingSchema, data);
```

This works fine for a single struct. But I am not sure how to deserailize it for an array of struct.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer directly by using borsh-js, but I am the author of an alternative library [borsh-ts](https://github.com/dao-xyz/borsh-ts) to make these kinds of specifications easier.

```js
import {
  deserialize,
  serialize,
  field,
  vec,
} from "@dao-xyz/borsh";

class SomeClass 
{
    @field({type: 'u128'})
    a: number

    @field({type: 'u128'})
    b: number
    
    constructor(data?:SomeClass)
    {
        if(data)
        {
            Object.assign(this,data)
        }
    }
}

class OtherClass {

    @field({type: vec(SomeClass)})
    q: SomeClass[]
    
    constructor(data?:OtherClass)
    {
        if(data)
        {
            Object.assign(this,data)
        }
    }
}
...

const value = new OtherClass( ... initialize ... );

// Serialize 
const serialized = serialize(value); 

// Deserialize
const deserialized = deserialize(Buffer.from(serialized),OtherClass);
```